# Node.js (nodemailer) contact form works on a local host server but not when the site is live. What can I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-hosting, nodemailer

I have a contact form on my website that I created with Node.js. When I run the site as a local host (localhost:5000), everything works fine. I fill out the contact form and when I hit send, I get a thank you alert and the email goes through.

However, once I connected my site to a domain and had it live, it no longer works - I get the "invalid login" message. I wrote an "if statement" in JS to return this "invalid login" error if the request does not go through, which is what I keep getting.

Could it be that I am not connecting to the correct server?

I'm guessing the xhr variable I use in my code is not valid once I begin using an actual hosting service. If so, how can I fix that?

Here is my code.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
console.log('submit clicked')

let formData = {
    email: email.value,
    level: password.value,
    amount: amount.value,
    service: service.value,
    details: details.value,
    email: email.value
}

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/');
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);

    if (xhr.responseText == 'success'){
        alert('Thank you! An Ogma representative will contact you shortly.');
        email.value = '';
        password.value = '';
        amount.value = '';
        service.value = '';
        details.value = '';
        email.value = '';
    }else{
        alert('Invalid login')
    }

}

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData));


})
```

Edit: Here is my code with nodemailer. It is my Server.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Middleware
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/Request.html')
})

app.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '//kept hidden',
            pass: //kept hidden 
        }
    })

    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email,
        to: '//kept hidden',
        subject: 'New message from Ogma',
        text: [req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.amount, `req.body.service, req.body.details].join('\n\n')`
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) =>{ 
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.send('error');
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            res.send('success')
        }
    })
})


app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('Server running on port ${PORT}')
})
```

Comment: Where is your code where you used nodemailer?

Comment: @jkalandarov Just edited it in :)

Comment: And what is the actual response you get from the server? What is `xhr.responseText` is really `error`?  If not what is it? If it is `error`, then what does the server report at `console.log(error);`?

Comment: @t.niese I get "submit clicked" in the console. So everything is being registered, but the email itself is not going through. This is what the "error" would be. I'm not sure why the email isn't going through, though.

Comment: `I get "submit clicked" in the console.` that's not what I asked you. `This is what the "error" would be.` You assume the `xhr.responseText` is `error`, but you must check what `xhr.responseText` actually contains to track down the problem. (if it is`error` or something else). And if it is `error`, I asked you to tell me what the error you log **on the server** at `console.log(error);` is.

Comment: @t.niese Sorry about that - I misread your last comment. I just checked the errors on my server through my cPanel and the last error I got was from a few days ago which was unrelated to this (I fixed it, so it isn't an issue anymore). I think if I can make the PORT variable be my site's IP address it would be able to connect to the hosted server. Would you know how I can do that?

Comment: You need to focus on what I asked. And answer those questions. **What is the contents of `xhr.responseText`** (not what you assume it is, what is it's actual content)